# How i do fetch list of website from magento using python code?

Tags: python-2.7, magento-1.3

In this question fetch website list from magento using python.
In python code i have used xmlrpc,
I have already try this but error was occured my code is write below

```
result1=api.call('ol_websites.info',[1,])
print result1
```

How i do this, anyone can help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from magento.api import API
with API('url of magento instance',
                            'username',
                           'password') as api:

websites = api.call('ol_websites.list', [])
print "websites :",websites
```